# How replace data-bind tag with {{}} style bindings in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, knockout.js

I want to declare my bindings as with AngularJS, but I'm using the KnockoutJS library. That is, I want to use Knockout but with the syntax I know from Angular. E.g.:

```html
Today's message is: <span data-bind="visible:true,text:myMessage"></span>
```

I want to write using `{{}}` notation, like so:

```html
Today's message is: <span {{visible:true,text:myMessage}}></span>
```

How can I replace `data-bind` attributes with `{{}}` based syntax in KnockoutJS?

Comment: Have you seen http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/?

Answer (score 2):

http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/ is all you need.

Knockout Punches convert traditional KO syntax to something like AngularJS

`<div>Hello {{name}}.</div>`

I personally find it very easy to use.