# Making components behave like custom bindings with Knockout JS?

Tags: knockout.js

I create custom bindings like this:

```
<div data-bind="stackPanel:true">
    <list></list>
    <buttons>
        <button>A</button>
        <button>B</button>
    </buttons>
</div>
```

But is there any way to declare a component with some kind of `init` without having the component apply its own template and viewmodel? In this case the `<list>` and `<buttons>` have their own view models.

```
<stack-panel>
    <list></list>
    <buttons>
        <button>A</button>
        <button>B</button>
    </buttons>
</stack-panel>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Please include additional code (e.g. for the view model), and tell us what you've tried with components so far.

Comment: Like Angular and others?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059204/how-replace-data-bind-tag-with-style-bindings-in-knockoutjs

Comment: @Michael Yes, more like an Angular directive that is initialized with custom code.

Comment: You might be able to extend or override some of the base functionality, but there is nothing like that out of the box.

Comment: This is not a full answer, but hopefully it will give you some insights.

There is a way to grab those inner nodes by using [componentInfo](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-createviewmodel-factory-function) parameter. (Note: the last parameter to CreateViewModel function)